# No cargan mis estilos ni imagenes en github pages

Tags: sass, img, github-pages

Es una pagina estatica, es primera vez que uso sass, no se si sea por eso. porfavor y gracias les adjunto la pagina

https://luispuent3.github.io/Recetario/

https://github.com/LuisPuent3/Recetario

Comment: En lugar de colocar las referencias así `href="/assets/css/estilos.css"` colócalas así `href="./assets/css/estilos.css"`. Lo mismo para las imágenes y tus scripts.

Comment: muchas gracias bro me sirvio, si era ese el error